# Streaming ffmpeg to storage

Tags: function, storage

When transcoding, FFMPEG writable streams do no property transcode to storage

FFMPEG allows streams in output and input. When creating writable and readable streams through gcp storage and applying them to FFMPEG, the output does not contain a valid FLAC transcoding.

This works asynchronously, locally, when applying `.output` from an input on the filesystem. But when applied to streams, withing gcp function.. the result is transcoded incorrectly.

Triggers are from an incoming bucket and output is to another bucket

```
const ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");
const ffmpegInstaller = require("@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg");
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegInstaller.path);
const { audioBucket_3pg, audioBucket_flac} = require("./config.json");
const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");
const fs = require("fs");

/**
 * Triggered from a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
 *
 * @param {!Object} event Event payload and metadata.
 * @param {!Function} callback Callback function to signal completion.
 */
exports.transcode = (event, callback) => {
  try {
    const { name } = event.data;
    console.log("name", name)
    const flacName = name.replace(".3pg", ".FLAC");
    const storage = new Storage();
    const options = {
      gzip: true,
      metadata: {
        cacheControl: "public, max-age=31536000"
      }
    };
    const readFile = storage.bucket(audioBucket_3pg).file(name);
    const tempReadStream = fs.createReadStream('temp.flac')

    const writeFile = storage.bucket(audioBucket_flac).file(flacName);
    ffmpeg(readFile.createReadStream(options))
      .pipe(writeFile.createWriteStream(options))
      // tempReadStream.pipe()
    callback(console.log("finished"));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("error", err);
  }
};
```

Comment: disregaurd the     `const tempReadStream = fs.createReadStream('temp.flac')`

Comment: you can use the "edit" button to adjust your code and remove an unnecessary lines.

Comment: TY! I will give this a shot :)

Answer (score 1):

just change the following line

```
ffmpeg(readFile.createReadStream(options))
      .pipe(writeFile.createWriteStream(options))
```

to

```
ffmpeg()
      .input(readFile.createReadStream(options))
      .outputOptions('-c:v copy') // Change these options to whatever suits your needs
      .outputOptions('-c:a aac')
      .outputOptions('-b:a 160k')
      .outputOptions('-f FLAC')
      .pipe(writeFile.createWriteStream(options))
```

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a shot. Its probably time to refactor some of this code anyhow.